# Delete column from PostgreSQL (Heroku)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

I have a Django project on Heroku, database there -  postgresql.
So, during manipulation of migrations conflicts with the database arose. When I post a request to the project API, the error occurs

```
IntegrityError at /api/
null value in column "loan_approved" violates not-null constrain
```

But I no longer have this column in my database.
As far as I understand, this column was left over from old migrations and I tried to delete it directly:

```
cursor.execute("alter table my_table drop column loan_approved;")
```

then I check all columns in the table as follows

```
cursor.execute("Select * FROM my_table LIMIT 0")
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
```

But this column is still in the database. Can I delete it in theory?

Thanks, any help would be helpful

Comment: Are you checking from a different session? Did you commit after dropping the column?

Comment: no, the problem is that I had problems and conflicts during migrations, I removed some migrations and apparently "erased" the changes with this column. I'm just wondering if I can "crudely" remove a column from the base

Comment: If this cursor is correct, then following it up with `connection.commit()` is pretty much the only thing I can think of.

Comment: this is what I needed! Thanks a lot, I missed such a stupid mistake